# Hibernate exception Collection is not associated with any session

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, persistence

So, I have an entity, say **Entity1** which is in join with another entity, **Entity2**. Entity2 in turn, is in join with another entity, **Enitity3**.

I have Entity1.entity2 join as *OneToMany* therefore returns a List. The same in Entity2.entity3, it's also as *OneToMany* and returns a List.

Now I'm building a web service in which I call Enitity1 then i load entity2 `(i.e. List<Entity2> entity2 = entity1.getEntity2())`.

And for each entity2 i load entity3 `(i.e. List<Entity3> entity3 = entity2.getEntity3())`

The first time it runs the query correctly, but when it tries to get `Entity3` out of `entity2` `(i.e. List<Entity3> entity3 = enity2.get(1).getEntity3())` it throws the exception mentioned above:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1179)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1112)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:245)
at com.test.test.adapter.impl.TestDbAdapterImpl.getTestList(TestDbAdapterImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
... 86 more
```

Comment: Are you doing some lazy loading? What that exception means is that you closed your database session (which only loaded your objects lazily, basically just their ids). When you want them to get the actual objects, hibernate tries to connect to DB, but the session is closed, so it throws the exception.

Comment: please provide complete relevant code snippet

Comment: @MSach I'm sorry i cannot provide the full code as it is a work project and there are some policies that wouldn't permit that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried setting every fetch type to EAGER but still the same problem. Even though it'd be helpful to still know how to do this, I just changed a little the database structure so that the `Entity2.entity3` is joined as *ManyToOne* so it's not a list anymore and it seams to be working.